# how to fix cURL error 60 problem unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: laravel, php-curl, dingo-api

I used dingo/API library and i have problem with third API provider, the error is curl error 60 SSL certificate unable to get local issuer certificate.
Note that i used Debian 9 OS.

I tried to solve it by using cacert.pem but still not working with me. Is there any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of try I knew that the provider has blocked my access to his API, so after the block gone it's working successfully.